Add a new item in an ObservableCollection crashes the MAUI app in iOS
In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I use the Maui Community Toolkit. In my view model, I define this property:
[ObservableProperty] 
private ObservableCollection<GameVerbList>? _gameList;

At same point of the view model, I add a new value in this collection
GameList.Add(...);

This code is working fine with Android and Windows. In iOS, the application crashes and the error is not very clear

libsystem_kernel.dylib
__pthread_kill libsystem_c.dylib abort LanguageInUse 0x10065c000 + 3312336 LanguageInUse 0x10065c000 + 4931284 LanguageInUse 0x10065c000

4931396 LanguageInUse 0x10065c000 + 4931444 LanguageInUse 0x10065c000 + 4632768 LanguageInUse 0x10065c000 + 4641936
LanguageInUse 0x10065c000 + 5814296 libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_start libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start


As a workaround, I created a List, same the values there and then converted the list in the ObservableObject. Is there an issue with the toolkit?

Try adding this <MtouchInterpreter>-all,System.Collections.Immutable</MtouchInterpreter> https://stackoverflow.com/a/78556055/3392605

Yes, you can add the following code just as Mustafa Mutasim said.
For example:
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Release')) And $(TargetFramework.Contains('ios'))">
  <MtouchInterpreter>-all,System.Collections.Immutable</MtouchInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>

